# Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

Tags: vagrant-plugin

A frustrating error after running `vagrant up` in powershell but a plugin error pop out saying that the plugins failed to load properly

OS: Windows10 64bit
vagrant: 2.3.7v

i tried reinstalling Vagrant but still the same error as shown below

`**

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.
cannot load such file -- rack
Did you mean? racc**`
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that i only needed to run `vagrant plugin install racc` `vagrant plugin install rack`
and done :)